# C Socket Programming for SO_KEEPALIVE

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I have a TCP connection between a server and client. SO_KEEPALIVE option is not set on the client and server. If the client goes down, how will the server get to know if the client has gone down and if so, will the connection be terminated?

Comment: If you don't have keepalive you can still use read timeouts, and you will still get errors on send eventually.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you mean that if a client is suddenly disconnected and the connection is not gracefully closed?
Why is not SO_KEEPALIVE an option since this solve your problem?
If not, you need to implement some kind of keep-alive mechanism like sending a "hello I am alive"-packet on a timer.